# RestAssuredMockMvc.postProcessors(csrf().asHeader()); doesn't work when multiple tests get executed

Tags: unit-testing, post, junit, csrf, rest-assured

I have a RestAssuredMockMvc setup to to unit test my "POST" endpoints. I added

```
RestAssuredMockMvc.postProcessors(csrf().asHeader());
```

Since csrf() headers are enabled.
This works fine when I run a test individually (all the tests gets passed, if executed them one by one). But only 1 test at a time gets executed correctly (without returning 403) when all the tests in my class gets executed. If I remove that test, and run all the other tests, another test gets the chance and gets executed correctly without returning 403.
I tried adding the postProcessors like I have mentioned below.

```
@Before
    public void initialiseRestAssuredMockMvcWebApplicationContext() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.basePath = "https://localhost";
        RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext);
        RestAssuredMockMvc.postProcessors(csrf().asHeader());
    }
```

& tried adding it under each and every test as well.

I did some debugging in `CsrfRequestPostProcessor` to check if the  get different values for token from `TestCsrfTokenRepository` for each and every test. Noticed that for the 1st test execution `postProcessRequest` method gets 1 hit and for 2nd test execution `postProcessRequest` method gets 2 hits and so on (for 10th unit test `postProcessRequest`method get 10 hits).

[image]

Appreciate if someone can help me with this TIA.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it with

```
@Before
    public void initialiseRestAssuredMockMvcWebApplicationContext() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.basePath = "https://localhost";
        RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext);
        RestAssuredMockMvc.postProcessors(csrf().asHeader());
    }

    @After
    public void restRestAssured() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.reset();
    }
```

above configurations.

Source - [github](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/master/examples/spring-mvc-webapp/src/test/java/io/restassured/examples/springmvc/controller/MultiPartFileUploadITest.java)